# Why am I having to redeclare an extern function?

Tags: c

I'm currently reading Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment by Richard Stevens, and I wrote a basic program to test out how to create filesystem links. After that worked without a problem, I decided to implement some options, starting with the ability to specify `-s` via the command line to create a symbolic link instead of a hard link. To do this, I typedef'd `link_fn`, which is set to `link` unless the user specifies `-s` in which case it is set to `symlink`.

The problem is that I have to include `extern int symlink(const char* actualpath, const char* sympath);`, or I get the following error when I run the makefile:

```
link/link.c: In function ‘main’:
link/link.c:30:18: error: ‘symlink’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   30 |             fn = symlink;
      |                  ^~~~~~~
link/link.c:30:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [Makefile;31: link.o] Error 1
```

What's weird is I double-checked both the book and the man pages (`man 2 symlink`) and both of them say the `symlink` function is declared in the `unistd.h` header. My header section looks like this:

```
#if defined(__unix__)
    #include <unistd.h>

    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <sys/random.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/syscall.h>
    #include <sys/sysctl.h>
    #include <sys/sysinfo.h>
    #include <sys/termios.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/user.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    ...
#endif // OS-Dependent modules

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
...
```

I first made sure `__unix__` was defined, and both the `symlink` and `link` functions work without a problem, but only as long as I declare `symlink` as external, like so:

```
extern int symlink(const char* actualpath, const char* sympath);
```

I then ran `gcc` with the `-E` option to see if `unistd.h` was actually being included and, sure enough, it was being included successfully and the `symlink` function was right there:

```
extern int symlink (const char *__from, const char *__to)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2))) ;
```

So why is it that I'm getting a compiler error when I don't declare the `symlink` function prototype myself? And why is it that the `link` function isn't giving me this problem when they're declared in the same header file, in the exact same way?

Here is the `link` function, also from the preprocessor output I generated while debugging.

```
extern int link (const char *__from, const char *__to)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2))) ;
```

---

```
#if defined(__unix__)
    #include <unistd.h>

    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    // Removed for brevity
#endif // OS-Dependent modules

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#if !defined(FALSE) || !defined(TRUE)
enum { FALSE, TRUE };
#endif // TRUE || FALSE

// Why does the compiler require this declaration, and only for symlink?
extern int symlink(const char* actualpath, const char* sympath);

typedef int (*link_fn)(const char* path, const char* link_path);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0) {
            printf("\nUsage: %s <Existing Filename> <New Filename>\n\n", argv[0]);
            printf("Options: \n");
            printf("  -s    Create symbolic link instead of a hard link\n\n");

            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Existing Filename> <New Filename>\n", argv[0]);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    link_fn fn = link;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < (size_t) argc - 2; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) {
            fn = symlink;
        }
    }

    const char* existing_path = argv[argc - 2];
    const char* new_path      = argv[argc - 1];

    errno = 0;

    const int return_code = fn(existing_path, new_path);

    if (return_code == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[Error] %s\n", strerror(errno));

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program is being compiled using:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS="-std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic"
```

System Info

```
gcc version 9.1.0
Manjaro Linux 18.0.4
x86-64
```

---

## MRE

Here is a minimal example, on the counsel of Eric Postpischil:

```
#if defined(__unix__)
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int (*a)(const char*, const char*) = link;
int (*b)(const char*, const char*) = symlink;

int main(void)
{
    //
}
```

Running make yields the following output:

```
gcc -I include -E -o link.pp link/link.c
gcc -I include -S -masm=intel -o link.asm link/link.c
gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic  -I include -c -o link.o link/link.c
link/link.c:9:38: error: ‘symlink’ undeclared here (not in a function)
    9 | int (*b)(const char*, const char*) = symlink;
      |                                      ^~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile;31: link.o] Error 1
```

The preprocessed output is as follows.

```
 1  # 1 "link/link.c"
 2  # 1 "<built-in>"
 3  # 1 "<command-line>"
 4  # 31 "<command-line>"
 5  # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
 6  # 32 "<command-line>" 2
 7  # 1 "link/link.c"
 ...
12  # 1 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 1 3 4
13  # 25 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4
14  # 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
15  # 450 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
16  # 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
17  # 452 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
18  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
19  # 453 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
20  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/long-double.h" 1 3 4
21  # 454 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
22  # 451 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
23  # 474 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
24  # 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
25  # 10 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
26  # 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
27  # 11 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
28  # 475 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
29  # 26 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 2 3 4
... 
32  # 202 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4
33  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/posix_opt.h" 1 3 4
34  # 203 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 2 3 4
...
38  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/environments.h" 1 3 4
39  # 22 "/usr/include/bits/environments.h" 3 4
40  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
41  # 23 "/usr/include/bits/environments.h" 2 3 4
42  # 207 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 2 3 4
43  # 217 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4
44  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 1 3 4
45  # 27 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 3 4
46  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
47  # 28 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4
48  # 1 "/usr/include/bits/timesize.h" 1 3 4
49  # 29 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4
...
53  # 31 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 3 4
54  typedef unsigned char __u_char;
```

Other function declarations and enums are declared for about a thousand lines. Then, on line 1169:

```
  1169  extern int link (const char *__from, const char *__to)
  1170       __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2))) ;
  1171  
  1172  
  1173  
  1174  
  1175  extern int linkat (int __fromfd, const char *__from, int __tofd,
  1176       const char *__to, int __flags)
  1177       __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (2, 4))) ;
  1178  
  1179  
  1180  
  1181  
  1182  extern int symlink (const char *__from, const char *__to)
  1183       __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2))) ;
```

And skipping a few hundred lines of similar declarations:

```
  1416  
  1417  # 6 "link/link.c" 2
  1418  
  1419  
  1420  
  1421  # 8 "link/link.c"
  1422  int (*a)(const char*, const char*) = link;
  1423  int (*b)(const char*, const char*) = symlink;
  1424  
  1425  int main(void)
  1426  {
  1427  
  1428  }
```

Comment: I used `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep -E 'unix'`, which showed `__unix__`, `__unix`, and `unix` all defined with a value of 1. Then I used a good ol' `#if defined(__unix__)` print statement just to make sure, which sure enough worked.

Comment: You should reduce this to a [mcve]: Write just `#if defined __unix__` / `#include <unistd.h>` /  `#endif` / `int (*a)(const char *, const char *) = link;` / `int (*b)(const char *, const char *) = symlink;` and show the output of compiling that (the error messages it generates, or lack thereof), and then show the output of compiling it with `-E`.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that compiling into an assembly file seems to work fine (why are you doing that by the way?), but compiling to an object file doesn't work. What happens if you include the same compiler flags for all builds? Does it change the preprocessed output? Does it lead to errors creating the assembly file?

Comment: In light of [the answer from rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56352554/440558), I would guess that the relevant flag is the `-std=c17` option, which causes GCC to not include the platform-specific defines needed for the functions to be declared. If you do `gcc -I include -E -std=c17 -o link.pp link/link.c` (note the added flag) are the functions really declared in the generated `link.pp` file? The lesson here is to always use the same compiler options and flags to *all* build commands.

Comment: Woah, that worked. I wanted to see how far in the build process I could get, but I completely forgot to use the same flags. Trying to get assembler output with that `CFLAGS` variable failed too, and removing the `std` declaration like you mentioned made everything compile without a problem. I tried `c99` and `c11` with no other settings and they triggered the error, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `symlink` to be declared, you need to `#define` the correct [feature-test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), as indicated in the [`symlink` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html):

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       symlink():
           _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
               || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
```

You should get in the habit of using feature-test macros, although the Gnu headers generally allow you to omit them if you use the default `-std` option, or any `-std` option starting with `gnu`. `gnu` "standards" define the `_GNU_SOURCE` feature-test macro, which effectively bypasses all feature tests. That might be considered convenient by some, but it leads to annoying portability issues.

Although it is technically better to put the definition at the top of every source file, I find it more convenient to put `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` in my `CFLAGS`, which also guarantees that the definition comes before any `#include`.

Also, please be aware that if you want to accurately preprocess source code, you need to ensure that your CFLAGS are the same for the preprocessing command as for your compilation. Otherwise you might miss the fact that some symbols are not defined (or predefined) with stricter `-std` options.

Comment: That's pretty embarrassing, I consulted the manpage but I didn't read far enough down. Thanks a lot, I haven't used feature test macros too much, but this is definitely a lesson I won't soon forget